# MyBatis - IntegerTypeHandler seems not working

Tags: java, mybatis, primitive, typehandler

I'm trying to configure a default `IntegerTypeHandler` from `org.apache.ibatis.type` package of `MyBatis 3.2.1` on one of my **result maps**.

Given the following constructor signature:

```
public Activity(int id, String name, String color, ActivityType type,
            int idOfOwnerClient) {
    //validations and fields initializations
}
```

I'm trying to transform a `SQL NULL` value to an `int` with value `0`, because the field `int idOfOwnerClient` is optional, so, the database may have `NULL` values.

If a try to pass a `null` to a primitive type like `int`, an `Exception` will be thown, to solve that, I'm configuring a `TypeHandler`.

Here's a snippet of my `mybatis-config.xml`

```
<configuration>
    <typeAliases>
        <typeAlias alias="intTypeHandler" type="org.apache.ibatis.type.IntegerTypeHandler"/>
    </typeAliases>
</configuration>
```

and a snippet of my result map (notice the type handler of last arg element):

```
    <resultMap type="Activity" id="activityResult">
        <constructor>
            <idArg column="activity.id" javaType="_int"/>
            <arg column="activity.name" javaType="String"/>
            <arg column="activity.color" javaType="String"/>
            <arg resultMap="ActivityTypeMapper.activityTypeResult" javaType="ActivityType"/>
            <arg column="activity.id_client" javaType="_int" typeHandler="intTypeHandler"/>
        </constructor>
    </resultMap>
```

But, when I run a junit test, I get the following error (notice the `null` value at the end of the error):

```
org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is 
org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: Error instantiating class 
br.com.agrofficio.kpifarm.model.Activity with invalid types 
(int,String,String,ActivityType,int,) or values 
(2,Aplicação de Cal,FFFFFF,[Id: 1, Name: Plantio],null,). Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

As the stacktrace above proposes, I'm still getting a `null` value instead of `0`, even with the handler applied.

**Solutions that I tried *with no success***

**1.** Using the fully qualified name of the handler intead an alias on resultmap:

```
<arg column="activity.id_client" javaType="_int" typeHandler="org.apache.ibatis.type.IntegerTypeHandler"/>
```

**2.** Adding a type handler declaration on `mybatis-config.xml`:

```
<typeHandlers>
    <typeHandler handler="org.apache.ibatis.type.IntegerTypeHandler"/>
</typeHandlers>
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get exceptions because you are trying to use Mybatis' default `IntegerTypeHandler`, which doesn't support null values ([source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.mybatis/3.0.4_2/org/apache/ibatis/type/IntegerTypeHandler.java)).

In order to satisfy your requirements, you need to implement custom typeHandler, which will inherit from default `IntegerTypeHandler`.

[Here](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/configuration.html#typeHandlers) you'll find all information needed to implement your own typeHandler.

*If you don't know where to start with your own typeHandler:*
[This class](http://unicore.eu/documentation/manuals/unicore6/files/uvos-server-1.5.1/apidocs/pl/edu/icm/unicore/uvos/db/NullIntTypeHandler.html) is nearly exactly what you want. Looking at its interface makes it clear that:

- you should extend the default `org.apache.ibatis.type.IntegerTypeHandler`
- in your implementation both `getResult()` methods should be overriden

Comment: Thanks for you awnser @Michal. I've already read the source code of `IntegerTypeHandler` class, and according to the implementation of `getResult` methods, I believe it should works.
`getResult` makes a call to `ResultSet.getInt(String columnLabel)` that should returns `0` intead of `null`. Refer to the javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getInt(java.lang.String).

Comment: `IntegerTypeHandler` doesn't override `getResult`, therefore base class version of those methods ([defined](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.mybatis/3.0.4_2/org/apache/ibatis/type/BaseTypeHandler.java#BaseTypeHandler.getResult%28java.sql.CallableStatement%2Cint%29) in `org.apache.ibatis.type.BaseTypeHandler`) is used.

Comment: You're right that it calls `getNullableResult`, which then calls `ResultSet.getInt(String columnLabel)` which returns `0` for `null`, but it also sets `ResultSet.wasNull()` to `true`.
`ResultSet.wasNull()` is checked in `getResult` implementation of `BaseTypeHandler`, an if it returns `true`, the whole method returns `null`.

Comment: You're right @Michal. I ran my app as debug with breakpoints on both `getResult` and `getNullableResult`, and as you said, this is exactly what it does. Thanks for your help, I'm going to implement my own type handler. Have a nice week!